# How to handle the Date format in DD-MM-YYY in jQuery JavaScript dot net mvc application

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, model-view-controller

I have tried many solutions to implement the date in "DD-MM-YYYY" format but does not work.

Should not accept . or / or any other special character and alphabets
It should be - only
32-09-2022 is not valid your textce 32 cannot be the day so shall be errored out
31-06-2022 is valid and changes to 01-07-2022 since few months have 31 only
3 digits number shall not be accepted in month or day
one digit can not by typed in day or month (like 9 shall not be allowed, it shall be 09)
Month cannot be more than 12

alidations error msg shall be 'Date shall be in DD-MM-YYYY' format

**Solution:** its working for me above mention expectation.

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control calendar datepicker" 
    style="width: 100% !important;" placeholder="Select Date" name="fixdate" id="fixdate" 
    onblur="GetContName('fixdate')" maxlength = "10" 
    onkeyup = "DateContValidateSetLoSto('fixdate')" 
    autocomplete="off" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" >

    <span id="msgfixdate" style="display:none; color:red"></span>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
function GetContName(controlName) {    
    DateContVali(controlName)

}
function ResetDatePicker(controllName) {

    $("#" + controllName).datepicker('setDate', null)
   

}
function DateContValidateSetLoSto(controllName) {
    localStorage.setItem("Val", $("#" + controllName).val());
}
function ResetSpanText(controllName) {
    if ($("#" + controllName).val() != "") {
        $("#msg" + controllName).hide();
    }
}
function DateValidate(dateVal) {

    
    var resultDate = true;
    var DocDate = dateVal.split("-");
    var day = DocDate[0];
    var month = DocDate[1];
    var year = DocDate[2];
    
        if (day != undefined && (day > 31 || day.length != 2)) {
            resultDate = false;
        }
        if (month != undefined && (month > 12 || month.length != 2)) {
            resultDate = false;
        }
        if (year != undefined && (year.length != 4)) {
            resultDate = false;
        }
    

    var str2 = "/";
    if (dateVal.indexOf(str2) != -1) {
        resultDate = false;
    }
    return resultDate
}
function DateContVali(controllName) {
    debugger;
    if ($("#" + controllName).val() != "") {
        // if ($("#" + controllName).val().length >= 10) {
        if (!DateValidate($("#" + controllName).val())) {
            $("#msg" + controllName).text('Please enter date in DD-MM-YYYY format')
            $("#msg" + controllName).show();          
            ResetDatePicker(controllName);
            localStorage.removeItem('Val');
                       return;
        }
        else {
            if (localStorage.getItem("Val") === null || localStorage.getItem("Val")=='') {
               
                $("#msg" + controllName).hide();
            }
            else {
                if (localStorage.getItem("Val").length != 10) {
                    $("#" + controllName).val("");
                    $("#msg" + controllName).text('Please enter date in DD-MM-YYYY format');
                    $("#msg" + controllName).show();
                } else if (localStorage.getItem("Val").split("-")[0] > 31 || localStorage.getItem("Val").split("-")[1] > 12) {

                    $("#" + controllName).val("");
                    $("#msg" + controllName).text('Please enter date in DD-MM-YYYY format');
                    $("#msg" + controllName).show();
                }
                else if (!(localStorage.getItem("Val").match(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[-]\d{4}$/))) {
                    $("#" + controllName).val("");
                    $("#msg" + controllName).text('Please enter date in DD-MM-YYYY format');
                    $("#msg" + controllName).show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#msg" + controllName).hide();
                }
                localStorage.removeItem('Val');               
            }

        }
       
    }
    else {

        $("#msg" + controllName).hide();
        if (localStorage.getItem("Val") === null || localStorage.getItem("Val") == '') {
            
            $("#msg" + controllName).hide();
        }
        else {
            if (localStorage.getItem("Val").length != 10) {
                $("#" + controllName).val("");
                $("#msg" + controllName).text('Please enter date in DD-MM-YYYY format');
                $("#msg" + controllName).show();
            } else if (localStorage.getItem("Val").split("-")[0] > 31 || localStorage.getItem("Val").split("-")[1] > 12) {

                $("#" + controllName).val("");
                $("#msg" + controllName).text('Please enter date in DD-MM-YYYY format');
                $("#msg" + controllName).show();
            }
            else if (!(localStorage.getItem("Val").match(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[-]\d{4}$/))) {
                $("#" + controllName).val("");
                $("#msg" + controllName).text('Please enter date in DD-MM-YYYY format');
                $("#msg" + controllName).show();
            }
            else {
                $("#msg" + controllName).hide();
            }
            localStorage.removeItem('Val');
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take care in correctly spelling "JavaScript".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
((((0[1-9]|[1-2]\d)-(0[1-9]|10|11|12))|(30-(0[469]|11))|(31-(0[13578]|10|12)))-((\d\d([02468][48]|[13579][26]|[2468]0))|\d[048]([02468][048]|[13579][26]))|(((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-(0[1-9]|10|11|12))|(30-(0[469]|11))|(31-(0[13578]|10|12)))-\d\d\d\d)
```

To check if a date is valid and put it as the pattern value for the text box, then use `checkValidity` to check the validity of the date.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const datebox = document.getElementById('txtDate');

datebox.addEventListener('invalid', function(e)
{
  console.log('invalid date');
  datebox.classList.add('baddate');
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
  datebox.classList.remove('baddate');
  datebox.checkValidity();
});
```

```css
input.baddate
{
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<label for="txtDate">Input date in format DD-MM-YYYY</label>
<input type="text" pattern="((((0[1-9]|[1-2]\d)-(0[1-9]|10|11|12))|(30-(0[469]|11))|(31-(0[13578]|10|12)))-((\d\d([02468][48]|[13579][26]|[2468]0))|\d[048]([02468][048]|[13579][26]))|(((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-(0[1-9]|10|11|12))|(30-(0[469]|11))|(31-(0[13578]|10|12)))-\d\d\d\d)" id="txtDate">
<button>check date</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response this is running solution